# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /hermes/bosoraweb081/b2603/ipg.glcmcrusaders/cyc/wp-content/themes/Nimble/connect.php on line 5

Tags: php, wordpress, parsing

New to PHP...I am not understanding what is going wrong.

```
if (mysqli_connect_errorno())
   {
    echo "Uh oh..MySQL connection error: " . mysqli_connect_error ();
   }
```

my echo statement is what is coming up as the error.....is this wrong?

Comment: Sidenote: The function name is actually `mysqli_connect_errno()`.

Comment: Which line is line 5?

Comment: Line 5 is the echo "uh oh...MYSQL connection error: " line

Comment: Cannot reproduce this error given the code you've pasted.

Answer (score -1):

```
    if (mysqli_connect_errno() != 0)
   {
    echo "Uh oh..MySQL connection error: " . mysqli_connect_error ();
   }
```

The function is mysqli_connect_**errno**(); There is a spelling mistake ie mysqli_connect_**errorno**().

This functions returns error code value if there is any error else returns zero(0). so check if returned value is not zero then print error statement.

Comment: This is a **syntax** error at the parser level, nothing to do with mistyping the name of a function.